# Finding the modular of a Square Root of a product of many numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, roots

I am working on Quadratic Sieve and at some stage I need to find
$$
\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^n y_k} \pmod{N}
$$

Now the Product (inside square root) getting bigger and bigger (up to few hundred numbers) and I can't apply mod before square root operation. My question is, can I apply some sort of modulus inside square root to keep the product term down. Ultimately the result will be between 0 to N-1.

What I'm doing now, dividing the product by some $p^2$ and letting $p$ out of square root and applying the mod outside root when possible.

For an example, 
$$
\begin{split}
s &= \sqrt{625 \cdot 117649\cdot 529\cdot 707281\cdot 2565726409\cdot 2809}
     \pmod{1113911}\\
  &= 25 \sqrt{117649\cdot 529\cdot 707281\cdot 2565726409\cdot 2809} 
     \pmod{1113911} \quad \text{as } 625 = 25^2 \\
  &= 25\cdot 343 \sqrt{529\cdot 707281\cdot 2565726409\cdot 2809} 
     \pmod{1113911} \quad \text{as } 117649 = 343^2 \\
  &= 25\cdot 343 \cdot 23 \sqrt{707281\cdot 2565726409\cdot 2809} 
     \pmod{1113911} \quad \text{as } 529 = 23^2 \\
  &= 25\cdot 343 \cdot 23 \cdot 841 \sqrt{2565726409\cdot 2809} 
     \pmod{1113911} \quad \text{as } 707281 = 841^2 \\
  &= 165866225 \sqrt{2565726409\cdot 2809} \pmod{1113911} \\
  &= 1007397 \sqrt{2565726409\cdot 2809} \pmod{1113911}, \\
\end{split}
$$
the last step being so since $165866225 \pmod{1113911} \equiv 1007397$, and so on.

Is there any better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you choosing the square root?  For example, $\sqrt{529} \pmod {1113911}$ can be either $23$ or $1113911-23$

Comment: I do not store 529 directly, 529 is the output of another expression say Qi = (root+i)^2-N, where I just keep track of i. So, at some stage there are a sequence of many i's and I need to compute sqrt(all Qi's) mod N. here the numbers all looks like perfect square, in reality they may not. But the product (inside square root) must be a perfect square.

Comment: Don't you factor these $Q_i$ after sieving? (If you don't, how do you get the product to be a perfect square?) The factorizations should give you a representation of the *square root* as a product you could compute $\bmod N$.

Comment: is it feasible for your case to make the set of prime factorization of the $y_k$ and of $N$, and thus $N^2$, and deduct $N^2$ from the first set of exponents as many times as it is alowed ?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work @ G Cab. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't store them as I am sieving over few hundred thousand of those. The exponent vector contains only 0 or 1. @metamorphy.

Comment: Are you aware that almost all quadratic residues mod an odd number gives two or more values as roots ?

Comment: I knew two values, I never find more than two.